# How to access a non-Google MySQL server database (no Cloud SQL!) from Google Cloud Function in Python runtime using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions, database-connection, pymysql

I try to connect from a Google Cloud Function in Python runtime to an external MySQL server db that is not hosted by Google Cloud.

My "requirements.txt":

```sh
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
SQLAlchemy>=1.4.2
PyMySQL==1.0.2
```

Core code of the Cloud Function:

```py
from os import environ 
import sqlalchemy

db_user = environ["DB_USER"]
db_pass = environ["DB_PASS"]
db_name = environ["DB_NAME"]
db_host = environ["DB_HOST"]
db_port = environ["DB_PORT"] # if not used, default 3306 anyway

db_address = f"""mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}/{db_name}?charset=utf8&use_unicode=1"""
db_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_address)
```

When I test the Cloud Function in the "Testing" tab, pressing on `Test the function`, I get the error:

> ````sh
> for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can
> be found at
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging
> Details: 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal
> error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is
> overloaded or there is an error in the application. ```
> ````

And in the log:

[image]

Or as searchable text:

> Debug2022-01-07T14:36:29.221892880ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvaw7xewhjqj
> Function execution started
> Default2022-01-07T14:36:29.529ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvaw7xewhjqj
> OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this
> system, assuming 256k
> Debug2022-01-07T14:36:30.964665907ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvaw7xewhjqj
> Function execution took 1743 ms, finished with status code: 200
> Debug2022-01-07T14:36:50.088620704ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w
> Function execution started Function execution started
> Default2022-01-07T14:36:50.340ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w
> 2022-01-07 14:36:50,267 [ERROR]: Exception on / [POST] 2022-01-07
> 14:36:50,267 [ERROR]: Exception on / [POST]
> Error2022-01-07T14:36:50.341ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise raise value File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1936, in dispatch_request return
> self.view_functionsrule.endpoint File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py",
> line 99, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object())
> File "/workspace/main.py", line 139, in get_csv_in_tmp_and_move_to_gs
> engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_address) File "", line 2,
> in create_engine File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py",
> line 309, in warned Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise raise value File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1936, in dispatch_request return
> self.view_functionsrule.endpoint File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py",
> line 99, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object())
> File "/workspace/main.py", line 139, in get_csv_in_tmp_and_move_to_gs
> engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_address) File "", line 2,
> in create_engine File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py",
> line 309, in warned
> Default2022-01-07T14:36:50.341ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w
> return fn(*args, **kwargs) return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> Default2022-01-07T14:36:50.341ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py",
> line 560, in create_engine File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py",
> line 560, in create_engine
> Default2022-01-07T14:36:50.341ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w
> dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args) dbapi =
> dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
> Default2022-01-07T14:36:50.341ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py",
> line 163, in dbapi File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py",
> line 163, in dbapi
> Default2022-01-07T14:36:50.341ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w
> return **import**("MySQLdb") return **import**("MySQLdb")
> Debug2022-01-07T14:36:50.342294068ZMYCLOUDFUNCTIONdvawxkmbid1w
> Function execution took 254 ms, finished with status: 'crash' Function
> execution took 254 ms, finished with status: 'crash' ```

When I use a with statement for the connection lifetime, I get a slightly different content, but the problem is the same, it cannot connect to the db:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise raise value File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1936, in dispatch_request return
> self.view_functionsrule.endpoint File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py",
> line 99, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object())
> File "/workspace/main.py", line 177, in get_csv_in_tmp_and_move_to_gs
> connection = engine.connect() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 3204, in connect return self._connection_cls(self,
> close_with_result=close_with_result) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 96, in **init** else engine.raw_connection() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 3283, in raw_connection return
> self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 3253, in _wrap_pool_connect
> Connection.*handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection( File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 2100, in *handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection util.raise*( File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
> line 207, in raise* raise exception File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect return fn() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 310, in connect return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 868, in _checkout fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 476, in checkout rec = pool._do_get() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py",
> line 146, in *do_get self.*dec_overflow() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
> line 70, in **exit** compat.raise*( File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
> line 207, in raise* raise exception File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py",
> line 143, in _do_get return self._create_connection() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 256, in _create_connection return _ConnectionRecord(self) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 371, in **init** self.__connect() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 666, in **connect pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
> line 70, in **exit** compat.raise*( File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
> line 207, in raise* raise exception File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
> line 661, in __connect self.dbapi_connection = connection =
> pool._invoke_creator(self) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py",
> line 590, in connect return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
> line 597, in connect return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
> line 353, in **init** self.connect() File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
> line 664, in connect raise exc sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:
> (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server
> on 'MY_SERVER_ADDRESS' (timed out)") Default 2022-01-09T23:03:25.322Z
> MYCLOUDFUNCTIONearoz5s8jozu (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8) (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

I tested the same code and setting on my local machine and in a local Docker container and both can connect with the same connection string (db_url).

#### Question

How can I get the connection to a non-Google MySQL server?

#### Some ways to go perhaps

##### Idea

Is this just a permission issue, for example, should I add some permissions to my user's role?

##### Idea

Or could it be that Google Cloud Functions do not allow any access to servers outside the Google universe?

##### Idea

And if only Cloud SQL servers are accepted as sources in Cloud Functions (which might be the case since I found only guides for this case like the official one from Google: [Connecting from Cloud Functions to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-functions) or this [Example of how to use MySQL in a Google Cloud Function](https://gist.github.com/aerobless/8ef438b982837422b0b80053e46fc7b3)), could I somehow make the external server a Google accepted Cloud SQL server without actually uploading it there, or is there any other workaround?

##### Idea

The [connection example from Cloud Functions to Google Cloud SQL (MySQL)](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions) asks you to activate the Cloud SQL API as a first step and then uses sockets in the connection string:

```py
# Remember - storing secrets in plaintext is potentially unsafe. Consider using
# something like https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview to help keep
# secrets secret.
db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]
db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]
db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")
instance_connection_name = os.environ["INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"]

pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    # Equivalent URL:
    # mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_socket=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
        drivername="mysql+pymysql",
        username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
        password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
        database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
        query={
            "unix_socket": "{}/{}".format(
                db_socket_dir,  # e.g. "/cloudsql"
                instance_connection_name)  # i.e "<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>"
        }
    ),
    **db_config
)
```

Is it possible that without such API and without sockets to secure the connection, the SQL query cannot be fired to a MySQL server that is not a Google Cloud SQL server?

##### Idea

Or do I perhaps have to change to Google [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) instead to have the chance to run my own container there? See [Python flask app using google cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654837/python-flask-app-using-google-cloud-functions). It seems that large file sizes, which can certainly arise from SQL query results in csv, are not at all recommended in Cloud Functions, see [Streaming binary data from Google Cloud Storage to Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60273469/streaming-binary-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-cloud-function), and its comment:

> ... I do not recommend using Cloud Functions to process large files
> though. I would rather recommend other serverless options as App
> Engine, or Cloud Run. Large files processing may take a while and
> Cloud Functions timeout after a certain time.

##### idea

And the next comment mentions GCSFS (Python module) which probably does not offer querying an external db though:

> I did manage to get something working using GCSFS which allows me to
> open files in cloud storage and stream binary as if they were local.

## solution works

This is just to confirm that the accepted answer works by adding the VPC connector:

[image]

Which then needs to be attached to the Google Cloud Function which should use it. Under the function's "Details" tab, you should see:

[image]

and then the query against your server that is not part of Google Cloud should work.

Comment: Where is hosted your database? On GCP? on the project/another project? Elsewhere? Is the database have a public IP?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It is not on GCP. The db is on a server that is run in the local network, I can access it from inside a Docker environment. I query against this host using a remote connection, using the server name instead of its IP. I do not think its IP is public since up to now, the csv file resulting from the mysql query is uploaded to a URL only to be downloaded by another server outside of the internal network, and there is no way for the outer server to directly connect to the mysql db host. The idea was to replace the Docker+URL approach with CF+GS, just as a prototype.

Comment: If the database is not accessible, how to solve the issue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Well I thought the db would be accessible from Cloud Function CF. If not, that is also an answer, I did not expect that. Google seems to reduce the possible queries to only `Cloud SQL` (though I am not sure about that). And as to the other outer server that needs the csv in the end: that server *can* access Google Storage (GS) like the URL before. It just cannot access the internal network. Therefore the prototype idea, bringing a bit more order into that process, avoiding the maintenance of local Docker containers.

Comment: No you can query the database that you want!! If the database is on a VM, and in your VPC, you can create a VPC connector and attach it to your Cloud Function to access it. If it's deployed else where, either the database has a public IP, and Cloud FUnctions can directly access it. Or the database has a private IP and you need to create a VPN between your VPC and the private foreign network with your database, and again add a serverless VPC connector to Cloud Functions to allow it to your your VPC and the VPN to access the database. It's not a Cloud Functions issue, it's your network design.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere As the db is not in any Google cloud network, I was first wondering about: ["VPC network overview: ... A Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network is a virtual version of a physical network, implemented inside of Google's production network"](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc). It seems you mean to use the VPC connector to make the local MySQL db server part of Google production. "Configuring Serverless VPC Access: Connects to on-premises networks using Cloud VPN tunnels and Cloud Interconnect attachments.". Con: "Serverless VPC Access connectors incur a monthly charge.".

Comment: There is no magic!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Would you mind answering? Your VPC connector is the answer. I created that VPC connector and though I still do not get the connection done, it is the way to go. Your comment, your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database is on a VM, and in your VPC, you can create a [VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) and attach it to your Cloud Function to access it.

If it's deployed else where,

- Either the database has a public IP, and Cloud Functions can directly access it.
- Or the database has a private IP and you need to create a VPN between your VPC and the private foreign network with your database. And again add a serverless VPC connector to Cloud Functions to allow it to your your VPC and the VPN to access the database.